# prisma - make a field equal to another when it is created

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, prisma

I am working on a project. I have a user model as follows

```
model User {
  id          Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName   String?
  lastName    String?
  email       String       @unique
  slug        String       @unique @default()
}
```

Okay? I just want whenever I push a user to the database the slug to be set automatically to the id field!

I did this before in row SQL but wondering how to do this with Prisma!

I have searched and didn't find something relevant.

I am using Postgresql as my DB.

any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. According to this page [Prisma Unsupported SQL features](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate/include-unsupported-database-features)

Prisma does not support triggers and procedures!

But they enable you to add these to your migrations! Wonderful!

And, Simply to achieve what I wanted:
run `npx prisma migrate dev --create-only`

then open the migration file you just created

and add your triggers / procedures:

for my case, I want whenever there is a new user, his slug becomes his id. He can change the slug later.

I added these statements:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_auto_user_slug()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW.slug = NEW.id;
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER auto_user_slug
BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_auto_user_slug();
```

After that, just run `npx prisma migrate dev`

And now you have the functionality you desired! Great.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Prisma documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model#defining-an-id-field)  it should by achievable by

```
model User {
  id          Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName   String?
  lastName    String?
  email       String       @unique
  slug        String       @unique @default(USER)
}
```

My only concern is related with different type of those fields.

Comment: I am sorry but it seems that it does not worl

Comment: So maybe it's subject to Prisma creators, or maybe this is related with different types of values, or maybe postgresql does not support  this kind of table definition. It's still achievable by before insert trigger in postgresql.

Comment: I think I can just make the slug field nullable and after I insert a new User I can just update it with the slug equal to the User's id. 

This will be part of the business logic. 

Is this a good practice? knowing that the inserting is not frequent